# how to delete the posted adaptive messge in MSteams using c# code

Tags: microsoft-teams

the below code is getting error while deleting the message based on the channel id
public async Task DeleteSentNotification(
string conversationId,
string recipientId,
string serviceUrl,
string tenantId,
string name)
{
// Set the service URL in the trusted list to ensure the SDK includes the token in the request.
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);

```
        var conversationReference = new ConversationReference
        {
            ServiceUrl = serviceUrl,
           
            Conversation = new ConversationAccount
            {
                TenantId = tenantId,
                Id = conversationId,
                name = name,(AdaptiveCard Json)
            },
        };
        await this.botAdapter.ContinueConversationAsync(
          botAppId: this.microsoftAppId,
          reference: conversationReference,
          callback: async (turnContext, cancellationToken) =>
          {
             try
              {
                    // Delete message.
                   await turnContext.DeleteActivityAsync(conversationReference);
              }
              catch (ErrorResponseException e)
              {
                  var errorMessage = $"{e.GetType()}: {e.Message}";
              }
          },
          cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);

        // return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

DeleteActivityAsync has two overloads, but they're both basically aimed towards deleting an "Activity" (i.e. a specific message or thread). If you want to use the overload that takes in a conversationReference, then that means your conversationReference needs to have the ActivityId set (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.conversationreference?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#properties) for more on the property). Alternatively, you can use the overload that takes in an activityId (it looks like this: `public System.Threading.Tasks.Task DeleteActivityAsync (string activityId, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);`), and then you need to pass in the activityId.

Essentially, as stated at the beginning of my answer, you're telling it to delete an "Activity", but you're not telling it *which* Activity. See here for the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.turncontext.deleteactivityasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

Comment: IS there any possibility to get the activity ID based on the channel id and time stamp , having the conversation ID  and sent date and service url based on these parameters how to get the activity id.culd you please help me on this

Comment: yes I would guess so, but not done it before. Try use the Microsoft Graph, and get the channel messages, something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http . I don't imagine you will be able to remove a message unless you created it though - was it not sent from your own bot?

Comment: Yes the message is created from my bot using c# code.able to get the channel id and conversation id not the activity id while sending the message as an adaptive card

Comment: I presume you're sending the original AdaptiveCard then using `SendActivityAsync`? The return value from that method includes the id of the Activity - you should be getting it from there immediately, and saving it for later use.